# Select question tags depending on groups

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

I would like to select my question based on certain criteria.For example:
I want to select questions of Java but not related to [mobile] or [web] tags.The [mobile] tag include all tag's which come under mobile programming eg. (android,.. and any thing related to mobile programming).The [mobile] would be be something like a super-tag.Currently i can select questions like this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java -web -android
```

But in the above it's just a single tag and not a group of tags.Is there any option to select questions that have the tag Java but are not at all related to [mobile]or[web]or[database]?

Comment: So you are suggesting a tag hierarchy?

Comment: Yes,then it would be easy to filter out subjects which I'm not aware about.

Comment: Huge hierarchy's are not needed just 2 level is more than enough.
like [web] super tag including [struts,hibernate,spring,ajax..ect]
or [mobile] super tag including[android,android-sdk..ect]
and the link could look like
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java -[web] -[mobile].its just a suggestion.I think it will really be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have no plans to support this.

Comment: I just gave a suggestion because I thought it would be useful.Any way I hope you might change your plans in future.